Why is the DateTime with specified culture ´nl-NL´, written in culture that is set by the browser?
In Blazor Wasm, I use the following code to write today's date in LongDatePattern to the console. It works well for English, German, Spanish and French. But for Dutch, it writes the date in the browser's language setting style (en-US in my case)
@DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("D", new CultureInfo("en-US"))<br />
@DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("D", new CultureInfo("de-DE"))<br />
@DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("D", new CultureInfo("es-ES"))<br />
@DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("D", new CultureInfo("fr-FR"))<br />
@DateTime.Now.Date.ToString("D", new CultureInfo("nl-NL"))

Here's a Blazor fiddle.
Output:
Wednesday, July 17, 2024
Mittwoch, 17. Juli 2024
miércoles, 17 de julio de 2024
mercredi 17 juillet 2024
Wednesday, July 17, 2024

And here's a .net fiddle. In this fiddle the Dutch part is correct. Output:
Wednesday, July 17, 2024
Mittwoch, 17. Juli 2024
miércoles, 17 de julio de 2024
mercredi 17 juillet 2024
woensdag 17 juli 2024

What am I doing wrong in Blazor?

Might it have something to do with the fact that you have modified your system's culture settings? Have you tried new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("nl-NL", false)?

I don't think so. My system is German. Edge is English and the code results in English instead of Dutch. Chrome is German and here, the code results in German instead of Dutch. I tested your suggestion and it did not change anything.

How does the browser play into this? You're writing to standard output...

Ah sorry, this was just an example. My app is a Blazor Wasm app. I did not think, that this could affect the behavior, but I just tested it in a .net fiddle (https://dotnetfiddle.net/6ZWtYq) and here it works well.

Possibly the browser doesn't support that culture and it's falling back to system.

Try running that code from a .NET (core) console application and see what the output is. I suspect the output to be correct in that case and that code running from within the browser (which is what Blazer Wasm does) behaves different.

Seems like they have a lot of info on this...

I created a new console app and like in the .net fiddle, everything is fine. I edited my question, because it is obvioulsy relevant that it is a Blazor app.

@Charlieface I cannot believe that a very common culture like nl-NL is not supported by modern browsers.

@Flippowitsch the problem starts when you tried to hard-code the culture instead of letting the browser's culture, controlled by the user, be used. Second, browsers know nothing about .NET culture objects. Only the .NET WASM runtime does, which doesn't load all cultures to save space. Robby Cornelissen's comment links to the Blazor WASM globalization/localization guidance that explains all this. You can force loading all cultures. Or you can let eg input type='date' display dates properly

@Flippowitsch as for a very common culture ... supported by modern browsers you'd be surprised. The problem isn't the browser or HTML. It's JavaScript that is terrible at date and localization. Extra libraries are needed both for proper date/time manipulation and localization.
